# Why is my PHP/HTML form not sending me data

Tags: php, html

I am trying out PHP after years of inactivity, and I thought I had it but looks like I lost the touch. Can anyone see why I might not be getting any data sent to my email address?

HTML code:

```
<form name="Call Back Request" id="request-call-form" action="callbackrequest.php" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
        <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="phone">
        <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="thm-btn"><a href="https://rootlayertechnologies.com.au/callbackrequest.php">submit now</a></button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="success"></div>
    </div>

</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to      = "xxxxx@xxxx.com";
    $email_subject = "Call Back Request Form - Home Page | rootlayertechnologies.com.au";

    function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error . "<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors and submit the form again.<br /><br />";
    die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['phone']) || !isset($_POST['subject'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone  = $_POST['phone']; // not required
    $comments   = $_POST['subject']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp     = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if (strlen($subject) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Subject you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = [
        "content-type",
        "bcc:",
        "to:",
        "cc:",
        "href"
    ];
    return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email_from) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: " . clean_string($phone) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: " . clean_string($subject) . "\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n"
    . 'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n"
    . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    ?>

        <!-- include your own success html here --> 
        <p>Thanks for contacting us. We have received your request for a call back and a friendly member of our Product Solutions team will be in touch with you soon.</p>

<?php}?>
```

Comment: You've got a bunch of different things here which could contribute to the problem. You need to do some basic debugging.

Comment: Start by using a [markup validator](https://validator.nu/). You have at least one serious problem with your HTML. Putting a link inside a button is forbidden. The browser might be treating it as a link and not as a submit button.

Comment: `@mail` — You are surpressing error messages from your attempt to send email. If there is a problem, how would you know? Never `@` in PHP.

Comment: Your PHP doesn't output anything to the browser. You should test to see if you are entering your IF statement, and what the values of the variables you pass to `mail` end up being.

Comment: Follow the advice at [mcve]. Especially the part headed "Minimal". Figure out where your problem is by debugging. Don't just look at the whole script and throw your hands up in the air with a "It Doesn't Work!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would begin by removing the `<a>` tag inside the `<submit>` button. I think that by clicking the link, you may be just opening the page instead of submitting the form.

Then, on the PHP code, i would confirm that `$email_to` is properly set. (It may seem obvious, but it's always worth confirming.)
I couldn't test the code, but i didn't find any bugs *per se*. (Some things could be improved, e.g. lack of `filter_var` and perhaps `html_escape`, `addslashes`, or `strip_tags`.)

This leads me to think that the problem may be at the server level. So, here are some things to consider:

- `From:` **must** be an address from the same domain as the site (e.g. info@rootlayertechnologies.com.au). Keep `Reply-to:` as is, though.
- Ensure that the SPF record is properly set. You may also want to delve into DKIM and DMARC.
- Some hosting companies disable PHP `mail`. You may need to implement SMTP.

Comment: That seemed to be the problem. Thank you.
Now I only have one error where the form submitted does not arrive in the designated inbox.

Any ideas on that one?

Comment: Thank you. At least we're making progress. I'll dive into the PHP code now and update my answer.